# phpmyadmin shows blank screen after change of password in xamp

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, phpmyadmin

I have xamp installed in windows 8.

Apache:ports:- 444,8081
Mysql:ports:-3306.

yesterday I changed the phpmyadin password through http://localhost:8081/security/index.php.

So now my username is :root and password is :qwerty

PhpMyAdmin authentification:cookie
(saved in (File: E:\Xamp\security\security\mysqlrootpasswd.txt)).

XAMPP DIRECTORY PROTECTION (.htaccess)

username:balram
password:qwerty 
File: E:\Xamp\security\security\xamppdirpasswd.txt)

But now I cannot access Phpmyadmin as it shows a blank screen.

following is the config.inc.php values:

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'cookie'; 
// Authentication method (config, http or cookie based)
// Authentication method (config, http or cookie based)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'qwerty';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

ERROR LOGS

APACHE:
    [Tue Mar 31 22:01:07.006981 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4356:tid 324]           AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.

```
[Tue Mar 31 22:01:07.059012 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6780:tid 436]           AH00430: Parent: Child process 4356 exited successfully.

[Tue Mar 31 22:01:10.891319 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 6860:tid 436] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Mar 31 22:01:11.368110 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 6860:tid 436] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Mar 31 22:01:11.471185 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6860:tid 436] AH00455: Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 31 22:01:11.471185 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6860:tid 436] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul 17 2014 11:50:08
[Tue Mar 31 22:01:11.471185 2015] [core:notice] [pid 6860:tid 436] AH00094: Command line: 'E:\\xamp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d E:/Xamp/apache'
[Tue Mar 31 22:01:11.475158 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6860:tid 436] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2184
[Tue Mar 31 22:01:12.882847 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2184:tid 332] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Mar 31 22:01:13.380254 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2184:tid 332] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Mar 31 22:01:13.486309 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2184:tid 332] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

MYSQL ERROR LOG:

```
2015-03-31 22:01:12 1344 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-03-31 22:01:12 9c8 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-03-31 22:01:12 1344 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-03-31 22:01:12 1344 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-03-31 22:01:12 1344 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-03-31 22:01:12 1344 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-03-31 22:01:12 1344 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-03-31 22:01:12 1344 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-03-31 22:01:12 1344 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-03-31 22:01:12 1344 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-03-31 22:01:12 1344 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-03-31 22:01:13 1344 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-03-31 22:01:13 1344 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-03-31 22:01:13 1344 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.21 started; log sequence number 1743245
2015-03-31 22:01:13 1344 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-03-31 22:01:13 1344 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-03-31 22:01:13 1344 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-03-31 22:01:13 1344 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-03-31 22:01:13 1344 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-03-31 22:01:13 1344 [Note] E:\xamp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for   connections.
Version: '5.6.21'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

I tried manipulating  php.config.inc.php but to no avail.
steps given on websites didn't solve my problem

thanks in advance,
balram

Comment: you should access your mysql command line and reset the password there

Comment: Or you can execute it UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/01/how-to-change-the-root-password-for-mysql-in-xampp/

Comment: @Demodave thanks for replying,...what i want is phpmyadmin to work

Comment: @Demodave I changed password using  http://localhost:8081/security/index.php. but the problem persists.